# NodeJs/Lambda function returning data from readFileSync in an async method performance impact

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, async.js

I need to read and return an JSON file in a AWS lambda function (using Node 8+) which is done as below.

Just wanted to know if the `readFileSync` method in this `async` lambda function will have any impact on the server by blocking the nodejs thread?

I know that the `readFileSync` will actually wait for the file to be loaded before proceeding to the next line, but doesn't the `async` which is the wrapper method itself keep clear of any thread blocking scenarios? Not sure how this works. Please advise.

```
exports.handler= async (event) => {
    var response = { 
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": ""
    };    
    try {
       var data = fs.readFileSync('test.json');
    } catch (err) {
       return response;
    }
    response.body = data;
    return response;    
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No, in this case that's actually probably the most appropriate approach. AWS will spin up new containers when you receive multiple concurrent requests -- that's kinda crux of the serverless concept; you write functions are oblivious to concurrency management, so you're free to focus on what the function should actually do. In return the AWS lambda framework will make sure to scale up and down the actual number of containers executing your function based on current demand.

In fact, if you were to change the readFileSync to the async variant, you'd have to call the appropriate event callbacks to ensure AWS wouldn't kill your lambda while it was waiting for the file async result.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs Kim, Also wanted to know what will be the performance implication if this was not on AWS platform but a normal nodejs application/server? Is this a proper async code?